# show picture in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

i am trying to show an image on pygame. but it turns out pygame.error: Couldn't open aircarrier.jpeg. what does it mean? how can i solve it? here is my code

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640,480])
screen.fill([255,255,255])

aircraftcarrier = pygame.image.load("aircarrier.jpeg")
screen.blit(aircraftcarrier, [100,100])
pygame.display.update()

gameExit = False
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Make sure that the image name is correct and that it's in the same directory as your .py file.

Answer (score 0):

By defauly, `pygame` can only load uncompressed BMP images. It must be built with full image support for the `pygame.image.load()` function to be able to support `jpg` and other file formats.

You can test if `pygame` is built with extended image formats through the function, `pygame.image.get_extended()`. This returns `True` if extended image formats can be loaded.

You can read more about loading extended image formats [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html).